# Descargar Imagenes desde el servidor FTP con java

Tags: java, netbeans, apache, ftp

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que requiere la descarga de las imágenes desde el mismo servidor para mostrarlas en el programa.

La descarga procede pero al momento de ver el resultado de la descarga, llega corrompidas todas las imágenes.

Este es el código:

```java
        public boolean DescargarArchivo(String rutaServidor,int img,String tipo){
                boolean download = false;

                String filename= "img"+img+"."+tipo; //Nombre del archivo

               this.ConectarFTP();//Donde se abre la conexión al servidor con apache net

                try {
    //se crea el archivo para guardar la descarga
                     BufferedOutputStream bus = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Archivos/IMG/Temporales/"+filename));

    //Se descarga el archivo
                    download = this.cliente.retrieveFile(rutaServidor, bus);

                    bus.close();


                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ConexionFTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ConexionFTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                this.ConectarFTP();

        return download;
        }
```

Todo lo realiza correcto, pero llega corrompida la imagen.

Asi es como me llega:[image: Imagen corrompida]

Answer (score 0):

*Resuelto*

El problema es que realizaba una descarga no muy larga, debido al espacio de las variables.

El siguiente código fue el que me funciono:

````
```java

    public boolean DescarImagen(String ruta,String tipo,int img){
    boolean download = false;
        this.ConectarFTP();


        try {
            cliente.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            cliente.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String ServerPath = "/public_html"+ruta;
            String LocalPath = "Archivos/IMG/Temporales/img"+img+"."+tipo;

            File local = new File(LocalPath);

            if (local.exists()) {
                local.delete();
            }
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(local));
            InputStream is = cliente.retrieveFileStream(ServerPath);

            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
                os.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            download = cliente.completePendingCommand();
            is.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConexionFTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        this.CerrarFTP();
    return download;
    }
```
````